# Can I sell my primitive material which is intended to be processed in a factory software under GPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl

If I develop a parametric 3D mesh creation tool and license it under GPL (because it is dependent on some geometry libraries also under GPL), can I sell 3D mesh data for use with the tool and would these be subject to the GPL? Would the generated custom meshes be subject to the GPL too for the customers that bought these data and created/generated meshes from it using the tool?

Comment: "guide purchasers to use the tool to "cook" the primitive ones into final output models in a parametric way"
--> this is a tad cryptic, could you expand or elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your responding.  I have described the problem in another way.

Comment: When you say "does it violate the GPL..." do you mean: can I sell 3D mesh data for use with the tool and would these be subject to the GPL?  and would the generated custom meshes be subject to the GPL too for the customers that bought these data and created/generated meshes from it using the tool?

Comment: Can you update your question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, data that you read and write with a software tool (including GPL-licensed software) is not impacted by the license of the tool.
For instance, if you edit your own document with LibreOffice it is not subject to the licensing of LibreOffice. So here, assuming that the mesh data you sell are yours, the custom generated meshes from that data would be subject to whatever term you please.

Comment: Thank you.  What if it is in [this case](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/can-the-license-of-a-interpreted-program-data-be-not-restricted-by-gpled-run-ti)?

Comment: Well you need to be more specific in your questions: programs running in an interpreter are programs. Data is data.

Comment: I updated the question again.  Thank you for your helpful reply.